# Testing IOS create folder

Tags: ios, ipad, directory

Found a problem with the BNR IOS Programming book , archiving data, the directory did not exist. Easy enough to fix, using createDirectoryAtPath and seems ok BUT - how do I test it again? How can I delete that directory and re-run? Easy enough on the simulator, delete in finder, but on iPad or iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

You found `createDirectoryAtPath` in the NSFileManager docs. If you keep searching that page, you'll find more info on `removeItemAtURL:error:` and `removeItemAtPath:error:`.